# Having trouble aligning avatar image and user name text

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm creating a user profile page and I want the user name to be aligned to the right of the avatar. I'm using a picture for the actual avatar but I'll substitute the picture with 1px border which is showing the same thing. If you take a look at the user name it's correctly to the right of the avatar but for some reason the name is a few pixels below where the top of the avatar is. How can I fix this to make it so both the avatar and the user name are top aligned next to each other?

```css
.profile {
  max-width: 1220px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.banner {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

image {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
    
.banner-user {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
      
.avatar {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

h3 {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="profile">
      <div class="banner">
        <div class="image"></div>
        <div class="banner-user">
          <div class="avatar"></div>
          <h3>Admin</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the requested functionality you can add a margin at the top for your avatar. Check with different sizes and it will work.

```
.avatar {
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        border: 1px solid black;
        margin-right: 10px;
        margin-top: 5px;
        }
```

This worked for me in the way you asked. You can also use % value instead of pixels to make your website responsive.